# Как рисовать картинки (Graphics) на прямоугольнике? C#

Tags: c#, графика

Мне надо создать элемент Graphics на прямоугольнике (Rectangle). Но не понимаю как это сделать. Пример:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.Location = new Point(x,y);
Graphics g = r.CreateGraphics();
```

Но так не работает, поскольку для прямоугольника нету метода CreateGraphics().

Comment: [DrawRectangle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Рисовать можно прямо в прямоугольнике.

```
g.DrawImage(image, r);
```